# Ideal way to learn a new programming language

Tags: programming-languages

I have been trying my hand at php for quite some time but dont think i have reached the level of expertise i desired.I started reading an ebook and writing down all the code examples present there on my own,which i think is inefficient.
My question is addressed to anyone who's an expert in any programming language.I just wanna know how do you guys do what you do so well,and as i mentioned in the title,what is the most efficient way to approach a new programming language so as to gain maximum from it making it an enriching experience.I love coding,have studied quite a few languages but left them all at intermediate levels after learning the basics and some advanced portions.
Wanna excel at php,so any tips would be really helpful from any of you highly skilled programmers on the website.
Thanks!

Comment: This question would be better asked on the Programmers site - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks..will post the same there too!

Comment: Don't post it there, the moderators should be able to move it.

Comment: okay..Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that the most useful thing to do when trying to learn in programming is just to work at it. Just looking and copying someone elses code isn't going to get you very far, you'll learn faster by trying to attempt something, and you're probably not going to succeed for a while, but keep working at it, fixing bugs as you go, and it'll just start to stick.

Also the php.net documentation is pretty fantastic, so just keep that open as you go.

In php, try to make a basic dynamic site, then work your way up.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that takes you from intermediate to expert is a combination of: practice, reading other people's code, and understanding the language specification and libraries.

Once you are at intermediate level, your primary reference should be the language definition and library documentation, and for third party libraries, their documentation, and their code, as necessary.

You can also consult advance-level third party materials, and try to implement relatively advanced or fundamental programming concepts (e.g. continuations) in the language, to push your understanding.

Comment: I have seen people trying there hand at coding straight away,without having any prior knowledge and using the documentation to help them as they go to learn the language..do u reckon this is an efficient way to do it?any comments on my way of learning from an ebook?

Comment: @Yaman You need extra resources to start learning the basics (unless you are a bona fide programming genius, which I certainly am not). So, if you find the ebook helpful, go ahead. However, you should transition to consulting authoritative materials, because it contains more information, and it will reveal topics which are not covered in third-party materials. In addition, it can be worth consulting advanced-level third party materials.